# Yocto setting custom variables, global variables

Tags: python, bash, variables, yocto

The Linux system includes environment variables, such as HOME. Yocto contains variables such as WORKDIR, S, and D.

- When using them in the **bb** file, you can use `${HOME}`, `a=${WORKDIR}`
- Used in **bbclass**, `w=d.getVar('WORKDIR ')`, `home=os.genenv("HOME")`

But I want to add custom variables, such as `export ABC="19990909"`

- The result obtained by obtaining os. genenv ("ABC") in bbclass is None,
- I wrote to/etc/profile, but the result is still None

question:

- So how to add a variable in yocto that can be used in bbclass or bbfile? (global variable)
- What is the lifecycle of an environment variable

Comment: I don't know yocto, but can tell you about the 'lifecycle': Your statement defines the environment variable `ABC` to the current process and, since the environment is inherited to child processes, it is also available in the direct and indirect child processes of your process. There is one gotcha: A process is allowed decide to explicitly pass a **modified** or even **empty** environment to its child processes, hence breaking the inheritance chain - so you better know, whether or not your children or  grand-children are doing such nasty things.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place "global variables" into local.conf, "machine".conf, "distro".conf or maybe to layer.conf. Variables in these can accessible in other .bb or .bbclass files.

Comment: Okay, it can work.Thanks! So can we directly call os.getenv ('ABC ') in bbclass to obtain variable values here? Just like os.genenv ('HOME ')

Comment: I think in your .bbclass you have a BitBake's Python function. In this case you can use d.getVar("ABC") to get "ABC". Note, not all .bbclass has Python codes, it should be a special case for you at the moment.
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.4/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#functions-you-can-call-from-within-python